# Creating an API to pass an Array result in PHP

Tags: php, api

I am not an expert with PHP. I am creating an API in order to get some information from one of my website.

Here is the result of api.php:

```
array (size=4)
  'price' => string '29.90' (length=5)
  'activation_charge' => string '50.00' (length=5)
  'decoder_price' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'is_offer' => int 0
```

I would like to create an API which would send these information. Here is the sample API call :

```
www.example.com/api.php?product=11&user=kiran
```

How should I encode the array results so that I can read it through an API call. I hope, the question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: Cannot use `json_encode` to return the result array?

Comment: There are several formats. You could for example use JSON or XML. It all depends on what you want to provide. Some API's allow several formats to be returned by appending `&type=json` to the API for example

Answer (score 1):

**How should I encode the array results so that I can read it through an API call. I hope, the question is clear.**

- JSON is a popular choice

  - `json_encode` http://php.net/json_encode
  - `json_decode` https://www.php.net/json_decode
- XML is also another popular choice

  - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5
- CSV is popular depending on the data/application (and variants of; pipe-delimiter, etc)

  - `explode` http://php.net/explode

Comment: That link about XML is about parsing and not generating. Also there are better functions than `explode()` to parse CSV in php...

Comment: Feel free to make an edit to include links and functions :) But thanks for the info @HamZa - The link works fine for me :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return it to Javascript for example. The easiest way is to use JSON.

```
echo json_encode( $array ) ;
```

Which will output something like:

```
{ "price" : 29.9, "activation_charge" : 50.0, "decoder_price" : 0.0, "is_offer" : 0 }
```

Of course you can create your own format and decode it on the other side.